# convert a dict to a dataframe with one more level

Tags: python, dictionary, dataframe

i have a dict, whose two elements are two dataframes with same index and column names. Like the code below:

```
my_dict = {}
my_dict['df1'] = pd.DataFrame(np.arange(6).reshape(3,2),index = ['r1','r2','r3'],columns=['c1', 'c2'])
my_dict['df2'] = pd.DataFrame((np.arange(6)+10).reshape(3,2),index = ['r1','r2','r3'],columns=['c1', 'c2'])

my_dict['df1'] 
Out[1]: 
    c1  c2
r1   0   1
r2   2   3
r3   4   5

my_dict['df2']
Out[2]: 
    c1  c2
r1  10  11
r2  12  13
r3  14  15
```

How can i convert to the dict into one dataframe. Index will be kept same as the original one, but i have one more level for columns like the following:

```
    df1     df2
    c1  c2  c1  c2
r1   0   1  10  11
r2   2   3  12  13
r3   4   5  14  15
```

Comment: Did you try this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18262962/convert-dataframe-columns-to-multiindex

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Concatenate Pandas columns under new multi-index level](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23600582/concatenate-pandas-columns-under-new-multi-index-level)

Comment: As suggested in link above, you can try `pd.concat(my_dict.values(), axis=1, keys=my_dict.keys())`

Comment: Thank you! @student thats great.One minor question, the link mentions 'using d.values and d.keys this way should be avoided, since it's not guaranteed that the order will be maintained'. Do you know how to preserve the order?

Comment: I added the answer following the discussion pointed, you can check if it works.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try this:

```
df1=my_dict['df1']
df2=my_dict['df2']
df1.columns = [['df1']*df1.shape[1],df1.columns]
df2.columns = [['df2']*df2.shape[1],df2.columns]
df1.join(df2)
```

Comment: thanks. it works. but i think student's answer fit my case better, as i have to combine hundreds of dataframes in the same week.

Comment: yep student beat me to it!

Answer (score 0):

May be you need something similar to the [other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23600844/5916727). As discussion in other answer points out, simply using `pd.concat(my_dict.values(), axis=1, keys=my_dict.keys())` does not guarantee same order for `.values()` and `.keys()`.

So, instead `k, values = zip(*my_dict.items())` can be used to preserve the order and use them with `pd.concat`:

```
k, values = zip(*my_dict.items())
new_df = pd.concat(values, keys = k, axis=1)
```