# How do you update column headers to change a Single index dataframe into a MultiIndex dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, rename, multi-index

I have a dataset that arrives with commingled column headers as a wide dataframe that also has row groups. For instance, several types of furniture that have yearly row data and the column levels are product size and colors...
But for flattening the data to be processed/graphed, I have to create a color column (I know I can use `.stack()` or `.melt()` at that point)

Remaining Question: **I simply can't find how to let Python know that I need to rename these columns to two indices.**
Note: for the MWE I created a MultiIndex, but that was for an empty dataframe and I don't know how to REname the columns...

Unless maybe the solution is in the way I import the columns to begin with? I use Jupyter notebook, so It's currently just brought in with a plain call of:

```
df=pd.read_csv("filename")
```

Which is where the joint column name of size and color come from.

Honestly, I tried the solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18262962/setting-dataframe-column-headers-to-a-multiindex) but couldn't get to try the `rename()` because I can't get at the MultiIndex second level. With this [documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.MultiIndex.from_product.html) I can make the incoming sample wide data and show how it currently reformats to tidy data in `df_stk`.

For the way I want it to look, I understand how to create the dataframe from scratch (which I did for `df_multi`), but without knowing how to simultaneously rename and reindex the columns for `df_mix`, I am unsure how to get what I want... which is `st1`.

```
# Minimum Working Example of incoming data & attempt to flatten
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
colhead = ["Small Black", "Small White", "Small Brown", "Medium Black", "Medium White", "Medium Brown", "Large Black", "Large White", "Large Brown"]
rowhead = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([['sofa','table','chair'],[2011, 2012, 2013, 2014, 2015]])
df_mix = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(1,10, size=(15,9)),index=rowhead,columns=colhead)
df_stk = df_mix.stack()

# showing weird tidy with mixed colors and sizes
print(df_stk)

>Output:
 sofa   2011  Small Black     2
             Small White     3
             Small Brown     6
             Medium Black    5...


# Format of What I actually want to see as tidy data
colhead1 = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([['small','medium','large'],['Black','White','Brown']])
df_multi = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(1,10, size=(15,9)),index=rowhead,columns=colhead1)
st1 = df_multi.stack()
print(st1)

>Output:
                 large  medium  small
sofa  2011 Black      1       4      6
           Brown      4       2      4
           White      5       1      2
      2012 Black      1       6      2
           Brown      3       9      1


# Attempt to reindex
hierarch1 = ["Small", "Small", "Small", "Medium", "Medium", "Medium", "Large", "Large", "Large"]
hierarch2 = ["Black", "White", "Brown", "Black", "White", "Brown", "Black", "White", "Brown"]
df_mixfix = df_mix
df_mixfix.columns = [hierarch1,df_mix.columns]
print(df_mixfix)

>Output:
                Small                               Medium               \
           Small Black Small White Small Brown Medium Black Medium White   
sofa  2011           2           3           6            5            9   
      2012           4           4           4            9            2
```

...The main point is this is slightly different from all the other questions previously posted

Comment: It's unclear. See [ask]. Post texts instead of screenshot images, separate your explanation and code, and explain your 'remaining question' in English. Anyway, for the first question, try ```df_mixfix.columns = [hierarch1, hierarch2]; st1 = df_mixfix.stack()```.

Comment: @relent95 I updated the question to get rid of screenshots as I found the RTF button that let me preview and copied from the Jupyter notebook... so hopefully, it reads better!

Also, the following worked!

`df_mixfix = df_mix`
`df_mixfix.columns = [hierarch1,hierarch2]`
`st2 = df_mixfix.stack()`
`print(st2)`

>Output:
                  Large  Medium  Small
sofa  2011 Black      8       5      2
           Brown      9       8      6
           White      9       9      3
      2012 Black      9       9      4
`

Comment: @relent95 do you happen to know how to name the levels? I tried `df_mixfix.columns = ][[hierarch1,hierarch2], names=['Size', 'Color']]` but that didn't work... I got the idea from [documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.MultiIndex.names.html).

Comment: If you solved the problem, why not answer your own question? And you need to edit your question for conciseness. An explanation in your Python comments, such as 'Format of What I actually want to see as tidy data' is an important information and should be in the paragraphs. For changing the level names of a ```MultiIndex```, try ```df_mixfix.columns.names = ['Size', 'Color']```. And that question should be in the body of the question, or in a separate post of a new question.

Comment: @relent95 
> If you solved the problem, why not answer your own question?<

I didn't solve it, you did...I was just "responding to feedback after posting" and pointing out that it needed a print to show that there were no names, which wasn't something I could have known until I tried your fix.  And the `.names` worked as well, so thanks again.

Comment: I just realized that only named the hierarchy columns, to get the other two index columns named, you have to use `df_mixfix.index.names = ['Product','Year']`. Then the `.stack()` command will properly have the tidy data.

Answer (score 0):

Per the suggestions in the comments on the question, I have pieced together the answer. To rename the columns, and to label both the columns and the indices, the code should be using `.columns` and `.names`, respectively:

```
# Minimum Working Example of incoming data in wide format
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
colhead = ["Small Black", "Small White", "Small Brown", "Medium Black", "Medium White", "Medium Brown", "Large Black", "Large White", "Large Brown"]
rowhead = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([['sofa','table','chair'],[2011, 2012, 2013, 2014, 2015]])
df_mix = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(1,10, size=15,9)), index=rowhead, columns=colhead)

# Reindex by list and use .names to label dataframe hierarchy
hierarch1 = ["Small", "Small", "Small", "Medium", "Medium", "Medium", "Large", "Large", "Large"]
hierarch2 = ["Black", "White", "Brown", "Black", "White", "Brown", "Black", "White", "Brown"]
df_mixfix = df_mix
df_mixfix.columns = [hierarch1, hierarch2]
df_mixfix.columns.names = ['Size', 'Color']
df_mixfix.index.names = ['Product', 'Year']

# Stack for tidy data
stk = df_mixfix.stack()
df_stk = stk.stack()
print(df_stk)
```

This gives the output, in the desired format, with the proper labels, except for the last column, which should be named 'Sales' (and it fixed the wide format dataframe into a properly labelled MultiIndex):

```
Product  Year  Color  Size  
sofa     2011  Black  Large     1
                      Medium    9
                      Small     2
               Brown  Large     1
                      Medium    3
                               ..
chair    2015  Brown  Medium    4
                      Small     9
               White  Large     5
                      Medium    3
                      Small     9
Length: 135, dtype: int32
```